Keras running out of training data on second epoch no matter how much data i add
I am trying to make an image classifier. When running this it does okay on the first epoch, but at the beginning of the second epoch it runs out of training data, gives me a warning, then just starts the third epoch, and when thats done, it gives me another error on epoch 4, and so on.
I believe the problem is in the image data generator, because it doesnt restart after every epoch (i thought it always did that) but i didnt find any way to restart it after every epoch.
Here is the code:
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shutil

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1" 
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

train = 'train'
toclassify = 'toclassify'
results = 'results'
resultsyes = os.path.join(results, 'yes')
resultsno = os.path.join(results, 'no')


os.makedirs(resultsyes, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(resultsno, exist_ok=True)


size = (128, 128)
batch_size = 32  
epochs = 10


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2
)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train,
    target_size=size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='training',
    color_mode='grayscale'
)

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train,
    target_size=size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='validation',
    color_mode='grayscale'
)

print(f"for training: {train_generator.samples}")
print(f"for validation: {validation_generator.samples}")


steps = train_generator.samples // batch_size
steps_v = validation_generator.samples // batch_size #validation steps


model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32,(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=(size[0],size[1],1)),
    MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Conv2D(64,(3, 3),activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Conv2D(128,(3, 3),activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512,activation='relu'),
    Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=steps,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=steps_v,
    epochs=epochs
)

Edit 1: Here is the console log:
Epoch 1/10
D:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\trainers\data_adapters\py_dataset_adapter.py:121: UserWarning: Your `PyDataset` class should call `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in its constructor. `**kwargs` can include `workers`, `use_multiprocessing`, `max_queue_size`. Do not pass these arguments to `fit()`, as they will be ignored.
  self._warn_if_super_not_called()
14/14 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8s 353ms/step - accuracy: 0.5409 - loss: 1.9809 - val_accuracy: 0.5729 - val_loss: 0.6883
Epoch 2/10
 1/14 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2s 221ms/step - accuracy: 0.5312 - loss: 0.74472024-06-14 11:08:49.711665: W tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:404] Local rendezvous is aborting with status: OUT_OF_RANGE: End of sequence
         [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
D:\anaconda\Lib\contextlib.py:158: UserWarning: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches. You may need to use the `.repeat()` function when building your dataset.
  self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
2024-06-14 11:08:49.828859: W tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:404] Local rendezvous is aborting with status: OUT_OF_RANGE: End of sequence
         [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
14/14 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 11ms/step - accuracy: 0.5312 - loss: 0.7447 - val_accuracy: 0.5909 - val_loss: 0.6761

Any help would be much much appreciated <3
I tried:

Changing the batch size
Adding/removing images
Subtracting 1 from steps and steps_v in hopes that it would restart before the next epoch
Looking for an answer to this question on google
Using ai tools

I expected:

I expected it to just dont give me the warning and skip whole epochs because it messes up the pyplot after that and i cant tell whether the model is overfitting or not and i dont think its normal for it to do that


What error are you actually getting? Please include it verbatim.

Hi @dr-snoopy! Thanks for reaching out.
I added the console log.

Note that ImageDataGenerator is deprecated since TensorFlow 2.9. Looking into the source code of it, it seems that .samples returns the actual number of individual samples, but each iteration of the generator returns batches of samples. So try to divide by batch_size for the steps. For future-proof code take a look into TF Datasets (tutorial) (another tutorial)

What worked for me was not specifying the steps_per_epoch and validation_steps in the model.fit(). Just allow keras to calculate them on its own.
